# tree algorithm to do calulation on leaves and get the value to the root ,python

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, data-structures, recursion, tree

I have a tree and I want to loop over all nodes to give them a value (`score`) :

- `leaves nodes:` the value is given by doing calculation based on the attributes of the  node itself  and of it sisters (calculations can be made only on leaves nodes)
- `non leaf nodes:` they take their score from children i.e compare score of children which are leaves and get the highest one for example
  I could figure out the tree traversal but I'm kind of blocked how to affect scores based on the conditions listed previously.

**input tree:**

```
((((a:1,((b:1,c:1)d:1,e:1)f:1)g:1,h:1,i:1)j:1,(k:1,l:1)m:1,(n:1,o:1,p:1)q:1)r:1)root;
```

**traversing code:**

```
def trav_tree(n): 
       
    if not n.is_leaf():
        trav_tree(n.get_children()[0])
    sisters=[]
    sisters=n.get_sisters()
    print n.name,
    for sis in sisters:
        if not sis.is_leaf():
            trav_tree(sis.get_children()[0])
        print sis.name,

    n=t.get_tree_root() 
    trav_tree(n)
```

**Output:**

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r root
```

What I should do exactly is to calculate when I arrive to **a** I get the sisters I keep go down till leaves, calculate score of **b and c** than I take the highest score and give to **d** and then I can calculate the score of a and so on ...

What is the best way to solve this ?
ps: I'm working on python [ete2](http://pythonhosted.org/ete2/reference/reference_tree.html) for Tree Data Structure

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just add one attribute field to denote the highest score of its children for each none leaf node.

Then perform post-root traversal.

Comment: I didnt understand how will this help in initializing leaves first and then get the value up ?